# Ajax calender control doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I downloaded the ajax control tool kit Binary .net35 and unzipped the content. Then add a new tab in the toolbox as AjaxControlToolkit. Then click on choose items and then tick on the access data source and then browse to AjaxControlToolkit.dll. Then  put toolscriptmanager and then one textbox and then the calenderextender in the design. But the calenderextender doesn't appear in the design. So i try to show the calender in the design page by writing it's code in the source page. But on debugging it show error message.

The source code is:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
            PopupButtonID="Textbox1" TargetControlID="Textbox1">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

and the error message is:

> Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceBase' from assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Can anybody suggest a good solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what is going on. There are 2 fixes you can do. The "quick fix", although maybe not the fix that is possible in your scenario is to change your `ToolkitScriptManager` tag to a normal `asp:ScriptManager` tag.

If that solution is not one you can do, then you need to download the [.NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22) and install it on your machine that is hosting the web application. That should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot...i downloaded .net framework 3.5 sp1 and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ScriptManager on your page instead of a ToolScriptManager, it should be in your toolbar under "Ajax" I think...  Once added, try to run your page again and see if it works.  I think the error occurs when you don't have .NET 3.5 "SP1" installed.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i installed .NET3.5 SP1 and it is now working.